# Spring data mongo: forget complexe type

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a very weird behavior with spring data mongo 1.5.5.
I have an object A which contains this:

```
private List<Media> medias;
private List<Competence> competences;
```

When I do an insert with an A instance, spring data mongo inserts my object in mongo **without** the attributes competences.

After many searchs, I do a dumb thing, I swap my code like this:

```
private List<Competence> competences;
private List<Media> medias;
```

Now when I insert an object in mongo, my object contains competences **without** medias.

I do my insert like this:

`mongoTemplate.insert(a, "COLLECTION_NAME");`

This seems a bug into spring and not in my code because in BasicPersistentEntity used by spring, the attributes properties contains only the first complexe type.

The 1.5.5 version is the last before need to update spring 4 (I can't do this now).

How can I insert an object with several complexe types ?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds weird. Do you have a stripped down sample project to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I tried to create a sample but it works with. I can't give you my full model obviously so I have no idea about this problem.

Comment: Something very weird. It works fine with 1.2.1 version and not with 1.5.5